# Arduino / Android Remote Control

Tags: java, android, arduino

I'm developing an android app that communicate with arduino vehicle via the wifi network. 
I send the command via EditText field, where I use w,q,s,d to start, stop, turn left, and turn right. the solution is working very well...
but I want is to create 4 buttons instead that send the command directly to the arduino, and I have no idea which method I should call on click.

```
 public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
                    String str = et.getText().toString();
                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                            new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                            true);                    
                   out.println(str);
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Did you add the buttons in the layout file?

Comment: Yes I did add the buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can reuse the same method for all 4 buttons. Just distinguish them by their ids

```
public void onClick(View view) {
 String command = null;
 switch (view.getId()) {
      case R.id.button1:
        command = "w";
        break;
      case R.id.button2:
        command = "a";
        break;
      case R.id.button3:
        command = "d";
        break;
      case R.id.button4:
        command = "s";
        break;
  }

  try {
     PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                        true);                    
     out.println(command);
  } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

in XML:

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/button1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:onClick="onClick"
     android:text="w" 
/>

<Button
     android:id="@+id/button2"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:onClick="onClick"
     android:text="d" 
/>

<Button
     android:id="@+id/button3"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:onClick="onClick"
     android:text="s" 
/>

<Button
     android:id="@+id/button4"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:onClick="onClick"
     android:text="a" 
/>
```

Comment: @Nada in which way it did not work? what are your button ids?

Comment: it seems like it doesn't recognize the action I would like to send you all what I have and you can look through it, but I don't know how to copy it into this prescriptive :(

Comment: @Nada you can send over to iphoneetc@gmail.com

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just fixed it...I had to use the " String eol = System.getProperty("line.separator");" as well since I'm sending the command with carriage return.